# Call derived class instance method from parent class in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a parent class `Parent` and its child class `Child`. `Child` class contains a method `child_method` which I have to call from `Parent` class. I have tried a couple of approaches, one of them is below:

```
class Child < Parent
  def child_method(params)
    # ...
  end

  def some_other_method(params)
    Parent.call_child_method(params, &method(:child_method))
  end
end

class Parent
  def self.call_child_method(params, &callback)
    # Some common code which it's Child classes share
    callback.call(params)
  end
end
```

Below is the error that I get:

```
NameError Exception: undefined local variable or method `params' 
for <Child:0x00000000154f53e8>
Did you mean?  params
```

And in case you are wondering why I'm not directly calling `child_method` from `Child` class itself. Well, the reason beging that 2 different child classes duplicate that code which then call different methods with different params and the constraints are such that I can't return after calling the `call_child_method` from `Child` class and then make a call to `child_method`. I must call those methods(other child class has another method with different number of params) while I am inside 'call_child_method' only. Moreover, the old code was not written by me and due to time constraints I don't want to refactor the whole Design logic. So, what options do I have here ?

Comment: You've changed the code after someone answered. I suspect that the error message no longer applies, and nor does their answer. If that _was_ the problem, can you please revert the question to have "broken" code - otherwise this makes the question very confusing.

Comment: How are you calling this method? e.g. what line produces this error? The question is a bit unclear on this and the post is not truly viable as you have left out enough code to make it unable to be tested.

Comment: I apologize for that typo. The error message and my question remains the same.

Comment: *"The error message and my question remains the same."* -- If I run your code, I do not get any error message. Can you please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code already works, so I don't know what the question is.

However, one thing I will say is that there's a standard way to handle control flow like this, without resorting to `method` meta-programming: **`yield`**. You can do something like this:

```
class Parent
  def common_logic(params)
    # Some common code which it's Child classes share
    yield
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  def child_method(params)
    # ...
  end

  def some_other_method(params)
    common_logic(params) { child_method(params) }
  end
end
```

Comment: You could also, if desired, do things like: `yield if block_given?`, or `yield(other_variables)`

Answer (score 1):

Your code almost works, but you forgot the `def` keyword when defining the `call_child_method` method.

The following works on my system:

```
class Parent                                                                    
  def self.call_child_method(params, &callback)                                 
  # Some common code which it's Child classes share                             
    callback.call(params)                                                       
  end                                                                           
end                                                                             

class Child < Parent                                                            
  def child_method(params)                                                   
    p "The params are", params                                               
  end                                                                        

  def some_other_method(params)                                              
    Parent.call_child_method(params, &method(:child_method))                 
  end                                                                        
end                                                                             

Child.new.some_other_method("hello")
```

I get output:

```
"The params are"
"hello"
```